# Add key-value pair to a dictionary only if value is present

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I wanted to add a key-value pair if and only if the value has been declared/found previously. If there is no declaration of the variable, then I do not want to add the key-value pair in the dictionary.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Set fruits
      set_fact:
        fruits:
          name: "Apple"
          color: "Red"
          size: "Medium"

#    - name: set place
#      set_fact:
#        place: "Earth"

    - name: Add place if present
      set_fact:
        fruits: "{{ fruits | combine ({ 'place' : place })  }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ fruits }}"
```

Here's the output of the above script:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "{'name': 'Apple', 'color': 'Red', 'size': 'Medium', 'place': AnsibleUndefined}"
}
```

Expected output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "{'name': 'Apple', 'color': 'Red', 'size': 'Medium'}"
}
```

What changes should be done to obtain the expected output? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Basically, I am passing the updated dictionary('fruits') to another playbook as an argument. Is it possible to achieve this inline (by adding some command in the command where 'fruits' was updated) rather than adding a condition check using 'when' statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [*default*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default) to [*omit*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional). The operation will be omitted if the variable *place* is not defined

```yaml
    - name: Add place if present
      set_fact:
        fruits: "{{ fruits|combine({'place' : place|d(omit)}) }}"
```

Q: ***"Do not remove the already present 'place' field if variable *place* is not defined."***

A: Try this. Use default *fruit.place* if defined otherwise *omit*

```yaml
    - name: Add place if present
      set_fact:
        fruits: "{{ fruits|combine({'place' : _place}) }}"
      vars:
        _place: "{{ place|d(fruit.place)|d(omit) }}"
```

Comment: Hi @Vladimir,
Thanks for the response. This is exactly what I wanted. But, had a follow up question. Suppose the 'place' field is already present in the fruits, and there is no initialization of variable 'place' as in the example. Then, this particular code would remove the already present field in the fruits dictionary too. Any workaround for this? so that the already present 'place' field does not get removed.